# How to perform web scraping to find specific linked pages in Java on Google App Engine?

Tags: java, regex, google-app-engine, screen-scraping, web-scraping

I need to retrieve text from a remote web site that does not provide an RSS feed.

What I know is that the data I need is always on pages linked to from the main page (`http://www.example.com/`) with a link that contains the text " `Invoices Report` ".

For example:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/data/invoices/2010/10/invoices-report---tuesday-october-12.html">Invoices Report - Tuesday, October 12</a>
```

So, I need to find all of the links on the main page that match this pattern and then retrieve all of the text from those pages that is situated inside a tag called `<div class="invoice-body">`
.

Are there **Java** tools that help with this and is there anything specifically for **Google App Engine for Java** that can be used to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/overview.html

You can use the UrlFetch service to read www.example.com/index.html line-by-line, and use a regular expression to look for "Invoices Report."

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/index.html");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String line;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    checkLineForTextAndAddLinkOrWhatever(line);
}
reader.close();
```

You might need a different kind of reader if the link might be on multiple lines.